# How to read selected partitions of in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table partitioned on `ldt` (format `YYYY-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss`) column and the following are the partitions.

```
SHOW partitions test.emp_table;

partition
ldt=2023-02-26-00-47-01
ldt=2023-02-26-01-27-40
ldt=2023-02-26-23-48-06
```

How to read from the subset of those partitions using wildcards? i.e. how to load all partitions of a particular day or hour? The following isn't working:

```
select * from test.emp_table where ldt = "2023-02-26-%"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using comparison operators

```
select * from test.emp_table where ldt >= '2023-02-26' and ldt < '2023-02-27'
```

Alternatively, in case of Python API, it may be convenient to generate a list of partition values and use `isin`

```
emp_table.filter(F.col('ldt').isin(dates_list))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way of achieving this using wildcards?

Comment: There is rlike function. Check out here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html#string-functions. But I'm not sure how it works with partitions. Check out SparkUI on how much partitions you have read. It can happen that you read all the files first and then filter will be applied

Comment: And it would be regexp, not exactly wildcard

Answer (score 1):

Are you open to using the PySpark API? If so you're able to read files using a glob filter.

Relevant documentation:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#path-global-filter